# Replace XML element with text

Tags: python, xml

I have a strange, xml-like file which looks like this:

```
<line>
^FX czesc dostawcy^FS
^BY4,3,90^FT30,430^BCN,,N,N,N,D
^FD<param id="P_BARCODEIKEA" />^FS
^FT30,480^A0N,34^FH\^FD<param id="P_ARTYKULNAZWA" />^FS
^FT30,700^A0N,30^FH\^FD<param id="P_TODAY" />, <param id="P_CURRENTSHIFT" />,      
^FT520,600^A0N,120,120^FH\^FD<param id="P_LABELNUMBER" />^FS
^FT700,600^A0N,120,120^FH\^FD`1^SFnd,1^FS
^FX 30,410 GB800,0,3^FS
</line>
```

How can I replace, for example `\<param id="P_ARTYKULNAZWA" \/\>` with a text node in Python?

**example**: if parameter P_ARTYKULNAZWA = "10.10.10", would like to replace "<param id="P_ARTYKULNAZWA" />" with "10.10.10"

Comment: What do you mean by "a text node"? Do you already have code that parses the file as XML? If not, do you have a specific library in mind for parsing the file? Please note that recommendations for libraries are off topic on Stack Overflow, but the Python standard library does include tools for this. If you are unaware of them, you should start by doing some research, [as is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Apply an XSLT stylesheet with the following template: `<xsl:template match="line/param"><xsl:text>The text node you want here!</xsl:text></xsl:template>` and combine it with the _identity template_. Then call this stylesheet from Python.

Answer (score 1):

This XSLT transform will replace  elements with text. It can be integrated into a python script or you could use any conformant xslt processor. I kept the xslt selection narrow to your example, but the selection can be broadened as needed.

```py
import lxml.etree

xml_text = '''\
<line>
^FX czesc dostawcy^FS
^BY4,3,90^FT30,430^BCN,,N,N,N,D
^FD<param id="P_BARCODEIKEA" />^FS
^FT30,480^A0N,34^FH\^FD<param id="P_ARTYKULNAZWA" />^FS
^FT30,700^A0N,30^FH\^FD<param id="P_TODAY" />, <param id="P_CURRENTSHIFT" />,      
^FT520,600^A0N,120,120^FH\^FD<param id="P_LABELNUMBER" />^FS
^FT700,600^A0N,120,120^FH\^FD`1^SFnd,1^FS
^FX 30,410 GB800,0,3^FS
</line>'''

xslt_text='''\
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    
  <xsl:template match="param[@id='P_ARTYKULNAZWA']">
    <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>'''

doc = lxml.etree.XML(xml_text)
xslt = lxml.etree.XSLT(lxml.etree.XML(xslt_text))
new_doc = xslt(doc)
print(lxml.etree.tostring(new_doc, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

Result

```xml
<line>
^FX czesc dostawcy^FS
^BY4,3,90^FT30,430^BCN,,N,N,N,D
^FD<param>P_BARCODEIKEA</param>^FS
^FT30,480^A0N,34^FH\^FDP_ARTYKULNAZWA^FS
^FT30,700^A0N,30^FH\^FD<param>P_TODAY</param>, <param>P_CURRENTSHIFT</param>,      
^FT520,600^A0N,120,120^FH\^FD<param>P_LABELNUMBER</param>^FS
^FT700,600^A0N,120,120^FH\^FD`1^SFnd,1^FS
^FX 30,410 GB800,0,3^FS
</line>
```

Comment: @Parfait - I've never seen it aliased as `lx`.`from lxml import etree` is how the lxml tutorial does it and I've also seen it `import lxml.etree as ET` because of its similarity to `ElementTree`.